# Drawing two colored balls randomly from an urn without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains 5 blue balls, 6 red balls, and 7 black balls.

If both the balls drawn out of the urn are blue, then using combinatorics:

$$\frac{5 \choose 2}{18 \choose 2} = \frac{10}{153} ≈ 0.065$$

The question is, what is the probability they have different colors?

By thinking about the possible picks, so either a blue and a red ball, or blue and a black ball, or a red and a black ball (each possible combination regardless of the order they are picked). Then, again using combinatorics:

$$\frac{{5 \choose 1}{6 \choose 1}+{5 \choose 1}{7 \choose 1}+{6 \choose 1}{7 \choose 1}}{18 \choose 2} = \frac{107}{153} ≈ 0.669$$

Is this correct? If so, is there a simpler or faster way to solve the different color picks?

Comment: There is not really a faster way, but an alternative is $1-\dfrac{{5\choose 2}+{6\choose 2}+{7\choose 2}}{{18 \choose 2}}$

Comment: @Henry thank you for your feedback! If I had enough reputation I would upvote your comment.

Comment: @Henry: Never say never :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had $6$ balls of each colour, the probability that the second ball has a different colour than the first one would be $\frac{12}{17}$. Now repaint one blue ball in black. (Fortunately black paint covers blue paint well; one layer should do.) The probability that you draw the repainted ball is $\frac2{18}=\frac19$, and if you do, then the probability for the other ball to be different is $\frac{11}{17}$ instead of $\frac{12}{17}$. Thus the overall probability to draw balls of different colours is now

$$
\frac{12}{17}+\frac19\left(\frac{11}{17}-\frac{12}{17}\right)=\frac{107}{153}\;.
$$

Comment: Your approach is interesting @joriki , and I like it. I was thinking about an alternative like $(\frac{5}{18}*\frac{13}{17}) + (\frac{6}{18}*\frac{12}{17}) + (\frac{7}{18}*\frac{11}{17})$, but your answer seems simpler and shorter.